# Чтение файла без блокировки пользовательского интерфейса

Tags: c++, файлы, c++14

У меня есть приложение, которое моделирует 3D изображения клеток. Проблема в том, что файлы, которые хранят изображения большие и занимают несколько секунд на загрузку с помощью `std::ifstream`. Есть ли какие-то альтернативы чтению файлов (желательно без доп. библиотек), чтобы пользователь мог продолжать просмотр изображения, пока файл грузиться?

Comment: Читайте в отдельном потоке (thread)

Comment: @MBo каждый раз, когда хочу прочитать файл, создавать `std::thread`?

Comment: читайте асинхронно (в стандартной библиотеке средств для этого нет)

Comment: Да. Не забудьте о синхронизации - никого не пускать работать с данными до полной загрузки, потом известить главный поток о наличии новых данных.

Comment: @VTT а где есть? разве `std::async` не для этого?

Comment: Не знаю... `std::async` может позволить выполнить блокирующее синхронное чтение параллельно и использовать результат асинхронно.